# Angular 11 Mat-table pagination with grouping

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Facing an interesting problem with MatTable pagination and grouping at the same time.
In fact, I have 2 components with Mat-tables where I have Pagination+Grouping.

1. ComponentOne has no troubles. If I select to display 5 elements in a page, it will work as expected and grouping headers wont be counted.
2. ComponentTwo has troubles with page length when grouping is enabled. If 5 is selected , each Grouping-header is considered as an element, so in the end, I can have 2 real data elements + 3 grouping headers. (see the screenshot attached).

[image]

Maybe there is a param which will allow to enable/disable considering Grouping Headers as elements of actual MatTable? Or maybe something wrong in general with the usage of this elements.
Thanks for any help!
Code sample for the ComponentTwo (it's quite big so I will take only parts):

```
       <div *ngIf="!isSmall">   
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
            
            ----- / data view / ---

            <!-- Table header -->
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>

            <!-- Grouping -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="groupHeader">
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let group" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
                    <b>{{group.value}}</b>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Table data -->
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let group; columns: displayedColumns;" class="group"
                [ngClass]="{'amber-300 selected': checkboxes[group.vk_id]}">
            </mat-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let group; columns: ['groupHeader']; when: isGroup"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>

        <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="tablePageSize" [length]="groupsCounter"
            [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 50, 100]" (page)="setPageSize($event)"></mat-paginator>
    </div>
```

Typescript part is quite simple:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.groups);
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

the rest of the component code is data manipulations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is overwriting the _pageData method, which isn't very nice but seems to work. It would look something like this:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.rows);
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
this.dataSource._pageData = (data: Row[]) => {
  const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
  // find start/end index with groups excluded
  const filter = data.filter(r => !r.isGroup).splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  const start = filter[0];
  const end = filter[filter.length - 1];
  // return all data between first and last item (including groups)
  return data.slice().splice(data.indexOf(start), data.indexOf(end));
}
```

Inspired by the [mat table source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/table/table-data-source.ts#L284).

Comment: yeah, seems like it something that cold help. Your solution didn't work well, probably need some tune, but anyway now I see how I could manage what I display. Thanks a lot!